# Access Docker Desktop's volumes from WSL2 bash

Tags: wsl2, docker-for-windows

How to access the volume of a Docker Desktop app from Windows WSL2 bash? I can see the `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` just right from Windows Explorer, but from WSL2 bash this folder `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data` listing results in an empty set.

I'm using Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000

Comment: You should clarify you are using a Developers Insider Preview build of Windows 11.  There is a good chance the behavior is linked to that fact.

Comment: Just regular Windows 11

Comment: What does “regular Windows 11” mean exactly? Why isn’t that information in the question body?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Someone else asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087715/how-to-access-docker-data-from-linux-wsl2
but it also currently has no good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly older question dusted off by [@ADJenks' answer](https://superuser.com/a/1782458/1210833), which certainly will work.

But IMHO a better solution is the one I detail in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1778525/1210833).  Since that's a fairly long read, I'll repeat it here.  From inside a WSL2 distribution:

```
$ findmnt -a | grep "version-pack-data\s"
| |-/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data        /dev/sdf[/version-pack-data]          ext4          rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
# Using the block device returned (sdf in this case):
$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data -o X-mount.mkdir
$ cd /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data
```

The advantage here is that you will be using the native Ext4 filesystem.  Using `drvfs` will not provide native permissions, symlinks, and other POSIX features.

Comment: I don't get any results for `findmnt -a | grep "version-pack-data\s"`, my folder: "/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/" contains "data" and "isocache", and "data" is empty but it's often where version-pack-data is found. If I `grep "docker-desktop-data"` instead, I do find a disk. Your method then works after that.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe this method on the github ticket that I linked in my answer, it might help people.

Comment: @ADJenks Thanks for that info - What's your Docker Desktop version?  I was on 4.18 and I just updated to 4.19 -- I'm wondering if that's one of those things that have changed recently in the organization.  If you are also on 4.18 or 4.19, then I'm going to need to keep searching for the "why" here ;-).

Comment: 4.13.1, I haven't updated in a while I guess. It hasn't bothered me to.

Comment: @ADJenks I'm the same way.  I only updated recently because the HuggingFace Docker repo requires using the Beta `containerd` pull system in 4.18.  Usually I'm *way* out of date.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you have to re-mount it on a different path like this:

1. In powershell:

```
net use h: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data
```

2. In wsl:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/yourdockermount
sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/yourdockermount
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176#discussioncomment-831817

The above worked for me. It was also suggested to do it in one step like so:

In wsl:
`sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data' /mnt/yourdockermount`

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4176#discussioncomment-1458301