# In a WSL2 distro - what determines the files that appear under: /wsl/{some-other-distro}

Tags: windows, docker, wsl2

## The Context

I understand that docker-desktop's WSL2 backend works by creating 2 distros: `docker-desktop` & `docker-desktop-data`.

I can see the filesystems of these distros mounted in my Ubuntu WSL2 distro:

```
grant@BeastMini-II:~$ ls -l /mnt/wsl
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 100 Apr  1 09:12 docker-desktop
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  60 Apr  1 09:12 docker-desktop-bind-mounts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  80 Apr  1 09:12 docker-desktop-data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 197 Apr  1 09:12 resolv.conf
```

When I view docker-desktop-data through Powershell I can see the various files in the filesystem:

```
PS C:\Users\grant> ls \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data


    Directory: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                lost+found
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                .docker
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                tmp
d-----        01/04/2023     09:12                etc
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                isocache
d-----        01/04/2023     09:12                run
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                sbin
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                data
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                bin
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                mnt
d-----        01/04/2023     09:12                sys
d-----        01/02/2023     18:36                usr
d-----        01/04/2023     09:12                proc
d-----        01/04/2023     09:12                dev
------        26/01/2023     12:11        1813552 wsl-keepalive
------        01/01/1970     00:00        1955960 init
```

... but when I view the mounted filesystem in Ubuntu I only see a small subset of the filesystem:

```
grant@BeastMini-II:~$ ls -l /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Apr  1 09:12 data
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  1 18:36 isocache
```

## The Question(s)

Why do I not see the entire filesystem at `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data` in my Ubuntu WSL2 distrobution?

What determines what files will and will not show up in that mounted directory?

In a running distro - how is `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data` different from `/some/mount/path` after you have mounted `docker-desktop-data` to it manually with `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data' /some/mount/path`? I can clearly see more of the filesystem in the latter.

## What is *not* the Question

How to view the entire `docker-desktop-data` directory in a WSL2 distro - I already know that I can mount it with `sudo mount -t drvfs '\wsl$\docker-desktop-data' /some/mount/pat

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ls` in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<sup>**Note:** The information in this answer has been validated against WSL 1.2.0 and Docker Desktop 4.18.0.  The methods discussed below have changed in the past and will likely change again in the future.</sup>*

> In a WSL2 distro - what determines the files that appear under: `/wsl/{some-other-distro}`

The question title is a bit ambiguous.  I believe you are asking about `/mnt/wsl/{some-other-distro}`, but you left out the `/mnt` part.  Or you could be asking about the `\\wsl.localhost\<distro>` share (a.k.a. `\\wsl$\<distro>`).

For the latter, the rootfs for the distribution is provided as a share through `\\wsl.localhost` (the now-preferred version over the deprecated, but still available, `\\wsl$\`).

For `/mnt/wsl`, there is no automatic process for this - Each distribution (and even the end-user) can mount whatever they like under `/mnt/wsl`.  Docker chooses to do so in its startup, but you can also create your own mounts using something like [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1659355/1210833).

For `/mnt/wsl` itself, there are a few files that WSL automatically generates there so that they are available in all distributions:

- `resolv.conf` - The automatically generated resolver configuration, which is then symlinked into `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- (In the latest versions of WSL):  `/mnt/wsl/run` and `/mnt/wsl/user` which are then bind-mounted into their respective directories.

> Why do I not see the entire filesystem at `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data` in my Ubuntu WSL2 distribution?

> In a running distro - how is `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data` different from `/some/mount/path` after you have mounted `docker-desktop-data` to it manually with `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data' /some/mount/path`? I can clearly see more of the filesystem in the latter.

As you've noticed (or at least assumed), Docker Desktop does not mount the virtual drive for `docker-desktop-data` itself.  Instead, it creates a [bind-mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/432493) to a subdirectory of that drive (and a number of other bind-mounts to other subdirectories).  At a high level, `docker-desktop-data` seems to use a technique *similar* to the one in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1659355/1210833) on sharing files between distributions, in that, when starting up, it creates a bind-mount for the primary "shared directory."

From a regular WSL distribution, you can see the actual mount with:

```
$ findmnt | grep "version-pack-data\s"

| |-/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data        /dev/sdf[/version-pack-data]          ext4          rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

In this case, `dev/sdf` has been assigned to the virtual drive for the `docker-desktop-data` distribution.  That may change depending on the order in which you start distributions (and how many).

*If* we could access the `docker-desktop-data` distribution directly, that would be the equivalent of running (as root):

```
mount --bind / /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data -o X-mount.mkdir
```

And while you may already know this, for other readers, note that `/mnt/wsl` is a `tmpfs` that is created by WSL itself on each startup.  It is shared and accessible in all WSL distributions, and it is ephemeral -- Its contents (the mountpoints, not the data under them) will be removed each time WSL shuts down.

> What determines what files will and will not show up in that mounted directory?

With the above in mind, it should be apparent that what you see in `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data` is a combination of each of the bind-mounts, with the primary one being `version-pack-data`.

With a full `findmnt`, you'll notice a number of other `docker-desktop-data` mounts as well.  While reverse-engineering each of these is beyond the scope of any one answer, there are a few interesting ones.  From inside `docker-desktop`, run:

```
mount | grep iso
```

This will show you how Docker delivers the executables and libraries themselves.  These ISO's can be found in the Windows `Docker` installation folder (usually `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources`).  When a new release of Docker comes out, the ISO files are updated with the latest versions and then mounted into WSL.

---

Side-notes:

- You'll notice that the `mount` command only shows `/dev/sdf` being mounted on `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data`.  The same thing would happen if you created a bind-mount yourself in your preferred distribution.  E.g.:

  ```
  $ sudo mount --bind /home /mnt/wsl/test -o X-mount.mkdir
  $ mount | grep home
  # Doesn't find anything
  $ mount | grep test
  /dev/sdc on /mnt/wsl/test type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
  ```

  However, you'll get better info from `findmnt` (as above) or:

  ```
  $ cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep home
  1734 71 8:32 /home /mnt/wsl/test rw,relatime shared:501 - ext4 /dev/sdc rw,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
  ```
- As you may have realized by now, it's probably better to mount the `docker-desktop-data` drive as a native `ext4` rather than using `drvfs`:

  ```
  $ findmnt -a | grep "version-pack-data\s"
  | |-/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data        /dev/sdf[/version-pack-data]          ext4          rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
  # Using the block device returned (sdf in this case):
  $ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data -o X-mount.mkdir
  $ cd /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data
  ```

  This will provide native permissions, symlinks, etc.
- In the latest releases of WSL, more exploration can be performed from the root namespace, a.k.a. the Debug Shell.  In an administrative PowerShell, run:

  ```
  wsl --debug-shell
  ```

  This root namespace shows *all* running processes in each of the distributions, including `docker-desktop-data`.

  There's only one process running in `docker-desktop-data` (other than the default `init` and Plan 9 server, and that's `wsl-keepalive`.  I'm going to assume the obvious given the name -- That this is simply a long-running process to keep `docker-desktop-data` running and accessible.

  You can demonstrate this with (again, in the debug shell):

  ```
  $ cat /proc/$(pgrep wsl-keepalive)/environ | xargs -0 -I{} echo {} | grep WSL_DISTRO_NAME
  WSL_DISTRO_NAME=docker-desktop-data
  ```

  You can also explore the other distributions namespaces with `lsns`, `nsenter`, and others.  However, note that the lack of a shell or any other executable in `docker-desktop-data` seems to preclude using `nsenter` to explore *that* particular namespace.  However, exploring the `/proc/<pid>` for that that distribution can still be interesting.